# Using Android on a PND(portable navigation device)?

Tags: android

i'm looking for a PND on which i can install android.

For example: http://www.medion.com/de/electronics/prod/MEDION%C2%AE+GoPal%C2%AE+P4440+EU/30010109A1?category=navigation_28&recId=&wt_mc=de.intern.m-shop.pro-pla.on-ma&wt_cc1=m-shop_topseller_navigation-2-links&wt_cc2=30010109A1&wt_cw=30.2.8&utm_source=Internetseite-intern&utm_medium=Kachel&utm_content=navigation_2-links&utm_campaign=Kategoriekachel-Hotspots&utm_term=30010109A1

I would like to install Android - not on a mobile phone, like it’s commonly down - but on a navigation device. In doing so I want to completely remove the old operating system and replace it with Android. Is this even possible, provided the hardware matches Android’s requirements, or are there other criteria to be aware of ?

Unfortunately I have not found any implementations of this kind yet and am therefore hoping that you can provide me with some help in this regard.

Sincerely yours, Christian

Comment: Should be entirely possible, you wont be able to access the market from the device though as it would have to be verified as a featured device, which wont happen as it wont pass. But I think thats the only limitation you will have

Comment: You could try asking at http://www.forceclose.com/ - it's the Stack Exchange site for Android questions that aren't programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is going to be finding a device that let's you reflash its o/s. You might have to remove the Flash/EEPROM and reprogram it externally.

Your best bet is to look for one that is Linux based, but even then it may have some proprietary drivers so you might have no success without the cooperation of the manufacturer.

This is a very good question, though.

+1